# Apache 2.4 reverse proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy

I have devserver on intranet with ubuntu, apache 2.4. There is some service running on direct ports like yourtrack on  port 9000. 
When I connecting directly its working properly (http://devserver:9000/). 
But I want to make on this format. http://devserver/yourtrack

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use apache proxying to your application. So you declare the port 80 virtual host and the use proxy pass to proxy to the other port.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName devserver
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass /yourtrack http://devserver:9000/
 ProxyPassReverse /yourtrack http://devserver:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

WARNING: This could have adverse effect on the application you're running depending what it does with http requests.